# Wordpress bedrock plugins installed via composer are going into vendor instead of the plugins folder

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

This has just randomly started happening and i've never seen this so i'm not sure how to fix it. I came to reinstall all the plugins for a bedrock install from wpackagist and instead of going into web/app/plugins they are all installing in the vendor folder. They weren't doing this last time i installed them, here is composer.json, nothing has changed so i don't know what is going on:

```
{
  "name": "roots/bedrock",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "WordPress boilerplate with modern development tools, easier configuration, and an improved folder structure",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/bedrock/",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Scott Walkinshaw",
      "email": "scott.walkinshaw@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/swalkinshaw"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Word",
      "email": "ben@benword.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/retlehs"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "bedrock", "composer", "roots", "wordpress", "wp", "wp-config"
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues",
    "forum": "https://discourse.roots.io/category/bedrock"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org",
      "only": ["wpackagist-plugin/*", "wpackagist-theme/*"]
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:clickds/save-share-cart.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url" : "git@github.com:clickds/woocommerce-additional-variation-images.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.1",
    "composer/installers": "^1.11",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3",
    "oscarotero/env": "^2.1",
    "roots/bedrock-autoloader": "^1.0",
    "roots/bedrock-disallow-indexing": "^2.0",
    "roots/wordpress": "5.8",
    "roots/wp-config": "1.0.0",
    "roots/wp-password-bcrypt": "1.0.0",
    "wpackagist-plugin/woocommerce": "^5.7",
    "wpackagist-plugin/disable-gutenberg": "^2.5",
    "wpackagist-plugin/custom-field-builder": "^1.2",
    "clickds/save-share-cart" : "^1.0.4",
    "wpackagist-plugin/woocommerce-gateway-stripe": "^5.8",
    "wpackagist-plugin/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall": "^4.4",
    "wpackagist-plugin/w3-total-cache": "^2.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout": "^2.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/simple-taxonomy-ordering": "^2.3",
    "wpackagist-plugin/wp-mail-smtp": "^3.2",
    "glenelkins84/woocommerce-additional-variation-images" : "^1.9.2",
    "wpackagist-plugin/import-xml-feed": "^2.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/woo-variation-swatches": "^1.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/woo-custom-related-products": "^1.3",
    "wpackagist-plugin/purchase-orders-for-woocommerce": "^1.8"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6.0",
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": false,
      "roots/wordpress-core-installer": true
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "web/wp"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "test": [
      "phpcs"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems "WordPress boilerplate" works separately from WordPress core.
Generally, using composer, the installed packages are stored in the vendor folder and can be called by requiring autoload.php file in your project.

Comment: that's not the case here it's setup to install them in specific locations that's how it's done with wpackagist